# Count unique values for entire data set group by years

Tags: r, dplyr, count, unique

I have a data set that looks like this but is significantly larger, where the column pit are different values but occasionally the same:

| Date | pit |
| --- | --- |
| 11/23/21 | 456256 |
| 10/13/20 | 332874 |
| 11/23/21 | 456111 |
| 10/13/20 | 332845 |
| 1/3/19 | 456256 |
| 10/13/20 | 332874 |
| 11/23/21 | 456220 |
| 10/13/20 | 652874 |
| 1/3/19 | 456874 |

I want to find the amount of unique values for "pit" and then group them by year. I've tried the code:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(DM = format(Date, "%Y")) %>%
  group_by(DM) %>% 
  summarise(pit = n_distinct(pit))
```

Which gives the output:

```
  DM      pit
  <chr> <int>
1 2020    169
2 2021    427
3 2022    316
4 2023     10
```

But if I run:

```
n_distinct(df$pit)
```

It gives the output:

```
[1] 901
```

If you you take the sum of the first output (169+427+316+10) it is equal to 922, which is larger than the output for `n_distinct(df$pit)`, which is 901. I'm assuming this above code is counting unique values inside each year, which accounts for a greater total.

How can I count unique values and then sum them into the year of their first observation? This should result in a total that would match the correct number of unique values.

Comment: Is your date converted to Date class before the `format`?  Based on the data format showed, may be `library(lubridate); df %>% group_by(DM = year(mdy(Date))) %>% summarise(pit = n_distinct(pit))`

Comment: Also, do you have `NA` values.  In that case, you need `n_distinct(pit, na.rm = TRUE)` or else NA will be counted in each grouping i.e. `n_distinct(c(1, 2, NA))#
[1] 3` whereas `n_distinct(c(1, 2, NA), na.rm = TRUE)#
[1] 2`

Comment: Something like this: `library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(Date = mdy(Date)) %>% 
  summarise(min_year = min(year(Date)), .by=pit) %>% 
  summarise(pit = n(), .by=min_year)`

Comment: Note that the uniqueness is counted per year. eg if you had `2020 - 1` and `2021 - 1` you will have 2 distinct values even though they are both 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I count unique values and then sum them into the year of their first observation?

First filter so each value only shows up in its first year, then count unique values.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(DM = format(Date, "%Y")) %>%
  group_by(pit) %>%
  slice_min(DM, with_ties = FALSE) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(DM) %>% 
  summarise(pit = n_distinct(pit)) 
# # A tibble: 3 × 2
#   DM      pit
#   <chr> <int>
# 1 2019      2
# 2 2020      3
# 3 2021      2
```

---

Using this sample data:

```
df = read.table(text = 'Date    pit
11/23/21    456256
10/13/20    332874
11/23/21    456111
10/13/20    332845
1/3/19  456256
10/13/20    332874
11/23/21    456220
10/13/20    652874
1/3/19  456874', header = T) %>%
  mutate(Date = lubridate::mdy(Date))
```